# Automatically tag place in facebook ShareDialod

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-share, facebook-checkins

I have a problem with tagging place in share dialog. I am using this code

```
ShareFeedContent content = new ShareFeedContent.Builder()
    .setLink(text)
    .setPlaceId(id).build();
ShareDialog.show(context,content);
```

but `setPlaceId(id)` has no effect. I mean when the dialog opens the place is not tagged and I have to select it again

[image: actual behaviour]

I think that specifying place id should tag place automatically like this

[image: exoected behaiour]

I am testing it on android emulator and it shows this error but I don't know if it is related to the problem

[image: error]

**UPDATE**
I have tested it on real device and same problem

Comment: Are you using command line to send location data? Or do you expect emulator to work although it is a virtual device?

Comment: I am not using command line. I have set some test location from emulator UI settings.

Comment: I'd recommend using real device to confirm the problem is not specific to emulator

Comment: I have tested it on real device and same problem

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the code to

```
        ShareContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
            .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(text))
            .setShareHashtag( new ShareHashtag.Builder().setHashtag("io").build())
            .setPlaceId(id)
            .build();
    ShareDialog dialog = new ShareDialog(context);
    ShareDialog.Mode mode = ShareDialog.Mode.NATIVE;
    if (dialog.canShow( content, mode)){
        dialog.show(content,mode);
    }
```

and it worked. I had to see facebook SDK code